# Game of 2/9 (Interview at Facebook)

Tags: algorithm, math

I was asked this question: [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299684/in-the-game-of-babylon-if-one-user-starts-playing-how-can-we-calculate-wholl) at google. Similar question was asked during Facebook interview.

> Determine winner of 2/9 number game
>
> Two players play the following game: they pick a random number N (less than 2 billion) then, starting from 1, take turns multiplying the number from the previous turn with either 2 or 9 (their choice).
>   Whoever reaches N first wins.
>
> The candidate should write a function that given N decides who wins (first or second player?)

Will a basic random choice of 2/9 for multiplication work or they'd want us to add intelligence in making moves. For ex: start with multiplication with 2 and multiply with 9 only when you see the other person will not be able to reach N quicker than you?

What is the best way to approach these type of questions?

Comment: k..so in that case, we do need to learn from the current state and make a move predicting outcomes.. I'm sure the interviewer will be happy to know that once the non-intelligent design is done well in time.

Comment: So for a non-intelligent design do we choose 2/9 at random?

Comment: The interviewer would want you to add intelligence. When they ask "who wins?", they mean "which player can win the game, assuming optimal play?"

Comment: Does it still count as a win if a player _exceeds_ N? Otherwise, a great deal of Ns can never be reached. ex. there's no way to get to 3, starting from 1, and only multiplying by 2 or 9.

Comment: They share the same number, right?

Answer (score 9):

The best approach to this type of questions.

First you need to have the **basic understanding of the theory of games**. Really basic. That is you are conscious of the fact, that for a given number N there is either a winning strategy for player who starts or a winning strategy for his oponent. So you must assume that they both know the strategy and play the best moves they can.

Then you start to **become familiar with the game**. You practice on a low level. You quickly notice that for 2-9 the starter is winning, while for 10-18 he must lose. So your function is ready for a case of `N<=18`.

Then you start **thinking of a general winning strategy**. Knowing the strategy would give you the algorithm. After 5 minutes (the sooner the better) you understand that you won't fit in time to find the winning strategy, as it is not obvious in that case. So you decide to give the computer some basic principles and let it solve the puzzle for you. You know you'll use the recursion.

You try to find the rule for recursion. You may want to start from the end or from the beginning. I'll describe the approach from the end.

The goal of the game is to **push your opponent to the zone, where he must give you the victory**. And not get pushed to that zone yourself. From N/9 to N there is a zone for winning. If one is pushed to play from between N/9/2 and N/9, he must lose. (Because both his moves push his opponent to the winning zone.) So you write your function:

```
wins(n) {
  // returns 1, if starting player is able to reach
  // the range [n, 2*n) with his move
  if (n<=18) {
    if (n<=9)
      return 1;
    else
      return 0;
  } else {
    // I must push him to the zone between N/9/2 and N/9
    return wins(n/18);
  }
```

If you reached that point, you passed. There are details left, like whether to use float or int, whether to round up or down using int. But in general you showed the right way of thinking and you're ready to face the interviewer :)

**EDIT**: *Actually there is a mistake in the code above. "Winning" is not the same as "being able to reach the range (n,2n)". Maybe 2 functions are necessary here: `wins(n)` and `reaches_slightly_above(n)`. The latter would be called in a recursive way, and the values returned below 18 should be different, resemble the ones in the solution of [Peter de Rivaz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13367642/772981). However the solution below and the general approach should be ok.*

The **alternative approach, going from bottom to up**, would be to use the function:

```
wins(a,n) {
  if (9*a >= n)
    // I win easily
    return 1;
  else
    // if one of my moves pushes the opponent to the zone
    // where he's not able to win, then I win!
    return !wins(2*a, n) || !wins(9*a, n);
}
```

If they ask for `n`, you return the value of `win(1,n)`. The complexity of this algorithm is not obvious, but I believe it's logarithmic.

Comment: In the bottom up approach, shouldn't the first if be if( 9*a >= n || 2*a >= n) return 1?

Comment: The second condition is not necessary. If 9*a>=n, then it is not checked at all. If 9*a<n then the second condition is also false, so it never changes the value of the whole expression. `9*a >= n` gives always the same result as `9*a >= n || 2*a >= n`. It may be explained in words as *If I can win with the "9" move, I don't need to use the "2" move*.

Answer (score 6):

Since they must reach exactly `N`, this is only possible if `N` is of the form `2^a * 9^b`, with one of `a, b` allowed to be 0 as well.

Find `a` and `b` above: if `a + b = even`, then the second player will win, otherwise the first will win.

This is because, at each step, a player gets closer to either `a` or `b` by one, and therefore to `a + b` by one. So the problem reduces to: given `k`, if at each step a player must subtract 1 from `k`, which player will reach 0 first?

Comment: Was exactly `N` specified? I read this as reaching `N`, so `N` or above.

Comment: @A.Webb - I understand "reach `N`" to mean exactly `N`. He didn't say at least `N`.

Comment: Could be. If so, the players better be lucky then when choosing `N` or they are in for a boring conclusion to their game.

Comment: The problem says that N is taken randomly and less than 2 billion, not that it is a random multiple of 18.  The way I read the problem is that whoever obtains a number N or larger in his turn wins.

Comment: @Cyrgo - yes, it doesn't have to be a multiple of 18, I corrected that. As stated however, the game can end in a draw / have no solution if `N` isn't of the form `2^a * 9^b`. For `N = 11`, no one wins, because no one can reach 11. It says reach `N`, not reach or exceed `N`.

Comment: For 11:  1st: 2 or 9 (doesn't matter), then 2nd player chooses 9 and wins.  x=1  ->  x=2 (or x=9)  ->  x=18 (or x=81)  both larger than 11 (11 has been reached and exceeded).  So player 2 wins.

Comment: @IVlad one thing I don't understand is for example 1458 = 2*9*9*9, like you said `a+b=even` then player2 will win, but what if player1 multiplies 2, player2 multiplies 9, player1 multiplies 2 again instead of 9, then no one can win. Should we say if `a+b=even` then player2 might win? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 5):

The optimal play will normally be to play the opposite of the opponent's move except right at the start and end.

By comparing with a recursive solution, it turns out that the answer can be computed based on the most significant digit in a base 18 representation of the number-1 as follows:

```
def win29(n):
    if n<=9: return True
    n-=1
    while n>=18:
        n = n//18
    return n==1 or 4<=n<=8
```

Comment: +1 Very nice! I laid out the game play of the winning strategies explicitly in my answer.

Comment: @Peter de Rivaz Could you explain the code a little bit? I dont understand why we need to do `n-= 1` and  `n==1 or 4 <=n<=8`

Answer (score 4):

Whether just trying to meet or meet or exceed `N`, this can be solved by determining strategies that will always win in various cases. I'll present 5 cases (or 2 cases, the second of which has 4 sub-cases) that cover all `N` and give the winning strategy for each.

Consider `T = ceil( log(N)/log(18) )`, that is let `T` be the smallest power such that `18^T` meets or exceeds `N`.

If `18^(T-1) * 9 < N` then the first player always loses to an ideal opponent. Whenever the first player chooses a 2, the second chooses a 9. And whenever the first chooses a 9, the second chooses a 2. In this way, the second player's turn always ends at a power of 18. After `T` rounds, the second player wins. The first player cannot win at the prior round because multiplying by 9 is not sufficient to exceed `N` (so neither is multiplying by 2).

So, now let's consider  `18^(T-1) * 9 >= N` and choose the smallest `k` such that `18^(T-1) * 2^k > N`. There are four possibilities `k = 1, 2, 3, or 4`.

- `(k = 1)` First player wins. The first player can start with a 2, and then play as the second player did above, playing  the opposite number from the other player each subsequent turn until the next to last round. The second player will always be faced with a power of 18 times the initial 2. At 18^(T-2) * 2, player two can at most reach `18^(T-1)` by multiplying by 9, which isn't enough to win, and can at least return `18^(T-2)*4` which player one can multiply by 9 to win with `18^(T-1)*2`.
- `(k = 3)` First player also wins. This time player one starts with a 9 and plays as before. The second player will always be faced with a power of 18 times the initial 9. At 18^(T-2) * 9, player two can at most reach `18^(T-2) * 9 * 9 < 18^(T-2) * 18 * 8 = 18^(T-1) * 2^3`, so isn't enough to win, and can at least return 18^(T-1) by multiplying by 2 which player one will multiply by 9 and win.
- `(k = 2 or 4)` Second player wins.  Here the second player should play the opposite number as before, until near the end, so that each round player one starts with a power of 18. At `18^(T-2)`, player one can at most reach `18^(T-2)* 9 < 18^(T-1)`, so not enough to win. If he returns 18^(T-2)*9, player two wins with `18^(T-2)*9*9 > 18^(T-2)*18*4 = 18^(T-1)*2^2` If player one instead returns `18^(T-2)*2`, player two returns `18^(T-2)*4`. Player one can then make at most `18^(T-2)*4*9 = 18^(T-1)*2`, which is still not enough. And now player one can at least return `18^(T-2)*8`, which is enough for player two to meet the goal since `18^(T-2)*8*9 = 18^(T-1)*4`.

Comment: Well explained. Please comment what kind of person can pass this test. A brilliant one or the one familiar with this kind of puzzle, who just met a similar problem before.

Comment: @Jarekczek: it's not possible to say for sure without knowing what the interviewer is looking for. It's a common mistake to assume that a correct answer to the question "passes" that part of the interview, and an incorrect answer "fails" that part of the interview, and dismiss this as almost a borderline general knowledge question, since it's hard-ish to solve with no prior experience. More likely the question is intended so that the interviewer can watch the process you go through *trying* to solve it. If you find it easy thanks to knowing a bit of game theory, they'll ask another question.

Comment: I have now a different opinion on that subject. Although your solution is elegant, perfectly explained and contains also a strategy for players, it is too complicated to came up with during an interview. I believe the interviewer is given no more than 30 minutes. If you resign from knowing who wins, you can invent a simpler recursive algorithm like the answer of [srbh.kmr](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13366114/772981). I have still problems with understanding his solution, maybe I'll show another simpler alternative.

Comment: @Jarekczek It probably is quite possible to come up with this solution in 30 minutes, but I did not. The recursive/DP solution of [srbh.kmr](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13366114/1756702) would be good to come up with in an interview because it demonstrates the general problem solving technique. The next step would be to do what [Peter de Rivaz](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13367642/1756702) did and look for simplifying assumptions and patterns in the result. At your leisure, if you are curious and a bit stubborn, you can lay out the explicit strategy for the particular puzzle.

Comment: The answer is unfortunately wrong, let's consider `N = 18 * 9` (so `T = 2` and `k = 4`); following the answer, the second player wins. But he cannot, since the first can start with `9`, the second continues with either `2` or `9` (and cannot reach `N`), the first now continues with `9` and wins since both `9 * 2 * 9` and `9 * 9 * 9` reach `N`.

Comment: @TaThanhDinh Thanks. I believe I should have split out k=2 from k=4 and possibly have developed more cases. The problem you identified occurs when k=4 but my solution description assumes k=2. As this answer is about 10 years old, I'm not going to revisit at this time, but edits are welcome if you have the missing branch.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are supposed to think of an optimal-play from both players and decide who will win.

Here, a simple recursive thinking could lead you to a solution.

If a player is with number `n` and `n*9 >= N` then the current player will win the game.
else, He will pass on either `2*n` or `9*n`, to the 2nd-Player. 
Now, 1st-Player will lose the game only if both options provided by him(`2*n` and `9*n`) to the 2nd-Player lead to a winning number for 2nd-Player, otherwise he will have a chance of picking a winning number again.

Hence, we could write a recursive approach as following:
since, all numbers in game are going to be of form: `2^i * 9^j` we could write:

```
 F(i, j) = true; if (2^i * 9^j * 9) >= N
           !(F(i+1, j) && F(i, j+1)); otherwise
```

solution would be in `F(0, 0)`, whether the 1st-Player wins or not.

Comment: Would work, but it would be `O(2^log N) = O(N)`, which is quite a lot for `N` up to two billion. For the `reach or exceed N` interpretation I think we need smarter math.

Comment: I think above approach will work for exactly `Reaching N` as well, we only would have to input a valid `N` and change the base condition to `if (2^i * 9^j * 9) == N`. For complexity, I think a memoized implementation will be a lot faster than a naive one as we will be solving many common sub-problems. [currently, i wrote a quick memoized program for this and it works extremely well for N = 2-billion and beyond, as well]. Do you know how to gauge the new complexity with memoization in place, in general ?

Comment: Also, if we are to implement a DP solution for this, I think there will be `log_base2(N) * log_base9(N)` entries to fill up in the table. Hence, complexity is quite manageable for N=2-billion. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: +1: I suspect this is the expected solution.  There will only be about 300 entries in the DP table to fill up so it is very fast.  (If using C, do take care that the comparison does not overflow if you use 32bit integers. N fits in 32bits, but 2^i * 9^j * 9 may overflow).

Answer (score 1):

There are great answers if N can be divided by 2 and 9, and some good game theory approaches. Here is a simple dynamic programming approach in Javascript to provide the answer for any possible N.

```
function getWhoWins(n) {
    if(getWhichPlayerWins(0, 1, n) === 0) {
        console.log("First player wins for " + n);
    } else {
        console.log("Second player wins for " + n);
    }
}

// Returns 0 if first, 1 if 2nd player would win
function getWhichPlayerWins(currentPlayer, currentNumber, targetNumber) {
    if(currentNumber * 9 >= targetNumber) {
        return currentPlayer;
    }
    var nextPlayer = (currentPlayer + 1) % 2;
    if(getWhichPlayerWins(nextPlayer, currentNumber *2, targetNumber) === currentPlayer || getWhichPlayerWins(nextPlayer, currentNumber *9, targetNumber) === currentPlayer) {
        return currentPlayer;
    }
    return nextPlayer;
}
```

The time complexity of this solution is O(2*logN) = O(logN).

Answer (score 0):

The answer (I'm not 100% sure):

```
r = N mod 18

if r belongs to (1,9]  player 1 wins
if r belongs to (9,18) or is =1  then player 2 wins.
```

I don't have a full mathematic demonstration, so I could be wrong.
This should be the correct answer if both players (or at least one of them) know how to play it.

Do I get the job? :)

Comment: Probably not if you can't explain it :). If you don't have a full proof, the intuition behind it would also help.

Comment: I do have a half formed proof, so wouldn't have posted a random answer.  The proof is simple, but the margin in this page is too narrow to contain it.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. P1 always loses for N=37, but your theory says he wins. Ex. Suppose P1's first move is to multiply by 9. Then P2 will multiply by 9, for a total of 81. P2 wins. Suppose P1's first move is to multiply by 2. P2 will then multiply by 2, for a total of 4. Whatever P1's next move is, P2 then multiplies by 9, exceeding 37 and winning.

Comment: Oops, I missed that P1 loses when N % 18 == 1, so your theory correctly predicts P1's loss for N=37. But P1 also loses for N = 38 through 72, some of which disagrees with your theory.

Answer (score 0):

Two-player, deterministic games such as this are studied by *combinatorial game theory*. This frivolous game theory has no relation with the more useful game theory of Neumann and Nash popular in economics. The seminal work is a delightful book called Winning Ways by Conway, Berlekamp & Guy.

*Think*. For any game, either:

1. There is a strategy whereby the second player always wins, however the first player plays.
2. There is a strategy whereby the first player always wins, however the second player plays.

Your game is a special case, an *impartial game*, where the state of the game looks the same to both players. The best example is a simple matchstick game called Nim. It happens that all impartial games are equivalent to Nim (this is the Sprague Grundy theorem), so all impartial games can be solved completely.

---

Let's solve your game. The possible states of the game are the positive integers. We'll classify each state as either winning for the second player (we'll label such games zero '0' games), or winning for the first player (we'll label such games star '*' games).

The integers greater than or equal to N are all zero games, because at this point the game is over. Whoever's move it is has already lost.

States where the player whose turn it is can move to the zero positions above are star games. Thus the integers n, `N/9 <= n < N` are all star games - the winning move is to multiply by 9.

States where the player whose turn it is has no choice but to move to star position are zero positions again. So integers n, `N/9/2 <= n < N/9` are zero positions. Our player has lost.

And so on. Using the similar arguments we eventually classify all integers down to one.

---

For N=1000 say,

- Integers 1000 and above are zero games
- Integers 112 to 999 are star games (to win, multiply by 9)
- Integers 56 to 111 are zero games (the player can't win)
- Integers 7 to 55 are star games (multiply by 9 or 2 accordingly so to move to one of the zero games 56 to 111)
- Integers 4 to 6 are zero games (the player can't win)
- Integers 2 to 3 are star games (multiply by 2)
- The integer 1 is a zero game (the player can't win)

---

Generalising we reach Peter's conclusion https://stackoverflow.com/a/13367642/284795

Answer (score 0):

Interesting post, and answers. 
I'd be tempted to propose a theoretical brute force function that enumerates all combinatorial paths using 2/9 factors to N <= 2X10^12 (or as close as possible). 
I say "theoretical" because I'm assuming that kind of computing power is beyond even FB?