# Converting this recursive algorithm into iterative one

Tags: algorithm

I was having a look at this stackoverflow question:  [Game of 2/9 (Interview at Facebook)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364811/game-of-2-9-interview-at-facebook/)

In one of the answers it is stated that by comparing with a recursive solution it is possible to find this algorithm:

```
def win29(n):
    if n<=9: return True
    n-=1
    while n>=18:
        n = n//18
    return n==1 or 4<=n<=8
```

I guess the recursive algorithm would be this one:

```
 F(i, j) = true; if (2^i * 9^j * 9) >= N
       !(F(i+1, j) && F(i, j+1)); otherwise
```

What would be the mechanism or procedure (or comparison) to convert this recursive algorithm into the iterative one above?

Comment: Your recursive algorithm does not do the same as the above algorithm.

Comment: It seems it does the same when you call F(0,0) and n=N. At least it seems it should give the same answer, according to the link I give.

Comment: Call me stupid, but this pseudo-code style is really confusing to me. Is this any standard, or de-facto standard. I mean `n = n//18` ... or  `if n<=9: return True` but in the latter code example  `F(i, j) = true; if ...`. Da hell?

Comment: Please have a look at the question I am referencing. I think it is not the same language (or pseudocode) for both. But it is easy to understand what each algorithm does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what i can explain of algorithm :

1. `N < 18^k*x and  x>8 & x<18` : then player two wins because he can force a win by making put powers of 18 till x remains
2. `N < 18*k*x*9 and  x>8 & x<18` or `N<18*k*2*x and x>8 & x<18` : Using same analogy as 1. where player 1 makes moves 2 or 9 and then wins using 1. as he is player two in next move. Simplifying for remainder in both equations we get `r>=9*8/18>=4 and r<9*18/18<=8 and r>=9*2/18>=1 and r<18*2/18<2` for player 1 to win

Hence divide by 18 successively then check `n>=4 and n<=8 or n==1` for player 1 to win

If compare properly my explanation though i came to it by another way but it is comparable to recursive solution where `2^i*9^j*9` can be visualized as `18^k*x` and `F(i+1,j) as 2*18^k*x` and `F(i,j+1) as 9*18^k*x`